# Error in Quiz App

Tags: swift, syntax-error, uilabel

Hi I am trying to create a simple quiz app but I am getting an error where it doesn't show or increment the questions in the ui labels but it prints the answers. I know I am close I just couldn't find the issue. If you can help me out I would really appreciate it. I know it is a stupid mistake probably

```
import UIKit

struct Quiz{
    var question: String!
    var options: [String]!
    var answer: Int!
}


class QuizViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var QuestionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var Options: [UIButton]!

    var questions = [Quiz]()
    var qNumber = Int()
    var answerNumber = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        questions = [Quiz(question: "What is your name?", options: ["AJ","Sami","Daniel","Sazzad"], answer: 1),
                     Quiz(question: "What is your colour?", options: ["red","green","blue","orange"], answer: 2),
                     Quiz(question: "What is your pets name?", options: ["Kitty","Marley","Button","Snoopy"], answer: 0),
                     Quiz(question: "What is your flat number?", options: ["204","205","208","209"], answer: 3)]
        selectQuestion()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func selectQuestion(){

        if questions.count<0{
            qNumber = 0
            QuestionLabel.text = questions[qNumber].question

            answerNumber = questions[qNumber].answer

            for i in 0..<Options.count{

                Options[i].setTitle(questions[qNumber].options[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
            }

            questions.remove(at: qNumber)

        }

        else{

            NSLog("Quiz is completed")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func Option1(_ sender: Any) {
        if answerNumber == 0{

            selectQuestion()
        }
        else{
             NSLog("Incorrect Answer")
        }

    }

    @IBAction func Option2(_ sender: Any) {

        if answerNumber == 1{

            selectQuestion()
        }
        else{
            NSLog("Incorrect Answer")
        }

    }

    @IBAction func Option3(_ sender: Any) {
        if answerNumber == 2{

            selectQuestion()
        }
        else{
            NSLog("Incorrect Answer")
        }

    }

    @IBAction func Option4(_ sender: Any) {
        if answerNumber == 3{

            selectQuestion()
        }
        else{
            NSLog("Incorrect Answer")
        }

    }
```

Comment: This line `if questions.count<0`, make it `if questions.count>0`

Comment: Well, I hope you are a beginner in iOS development, because the way the code is right now.... It's kinda ticking me off XD, even though it shouldn't